Side effects of constructing an explicitly unused object
Say I have a struct that provides a method that does some work (has useful side effects) and then returns an instance of itself. Do I have to use that instance somehow in order to guarantee that the code having the side effects will execute?
As per C++ standard, RVO and NRVO can elide the "as-if" rule. However, I'd expect different behavior from Rust, especially when using the _ = ... idiom. Now I'm wondering if I'm wrong in doing so.
To give a concrete example, let's look at the esp_hal::gpio::Io::new() which calls Self::new_with_priority() and before returning an instance of itself sets up the io-driver as a side effect. Can I then use the function for its side effects, but explicitly discard the returned object, like so:
let _ = esp_hal::gpio::Io::new();

In contrast to C++, I'd expect the compiler to not elide the side effects. Furthermore, I would expect it to elide the construction of an Ioinstance. In fact, that's exactly how I'd interpret the semantics/intent behind the _ = ... idiom. Should I update my beliefs?

It depends what you mean by side effects, but most likely, the only side effect rust is allowed to remove is allocation. Any other extern function calls and volatile operations are preserved.

"especially when using the _ = ... idiom" that would be more likely to elide the entire thing than not, actually: _ = is a pretty surprising corner of the language in that it's an actual no-op, for instance if the RHS is a !Copy object *it won't be moved`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7d7178520605be4275c98f90576a2316 however like drewtato I don't think the langage semantics would allow eliding side effects even if you ignore the return value. Though I don't know how the compiler interacts with e.g. asm! blocks.

Note that C++ is allowed to omit the construction for a static but that's not what you're donig in your Rust example, the C++ compiler isn't allowed to omit that construction either.

It remains unclear to me whether Rust is allowed to elide side-effectful calls to Clone::clone for Copy types (see https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3197 for pertinent discussion).

@cafce25 Compilers in C++ are also not permitted to drop the side effects of initialization of static-storage duration objects. It can only happen, depending on certain criteria, that the initialization is delayed until the first (odr-)use of the variable (indirectly) from main (to support dynamic libraries). There are common linker options and such that make the behavior non-conforming though and a common mistake is to forget the odr-use. Compilers also tend to not consider odr-uses that are optimized away correctly.

"As per C++ standard, RVO and NRVO can elide the "as-if" rule.": Elision under these rules is not permitted to elide the initial construction of the object, just the copy/move-construction from the initial (temporary) object into the target object. Also, since C++17 RVO doesn't exist any more as such. Instead the language rules have been changed so that behavior is as if RVO was always mandatory.

@user17732522 Yea, my point was more that C++ doesn't allow removing the side effect in the C++ equivalent of the posted Rust code either.

@eggyal Thanks for the Clone::clone  for Copy types reference, very interesting!

It's important to note that you can destructure with let.  More generally, you can pattern-match with let as long as the pattern is irrefutable.
_ is the pattern that means "match anything at all and don't bind it."  In other words, anything that matches _ in a pattern will be dropped.
So we can infer from this that let _ = anything(); is almost1 semantically identical in every way to just anything();.  Using let _, the value returned from anything() is dropped because of the behavior described above.  Not using let _, the value returned from anything() is dropped at the end of the statement because it is an unused temporary value.
All that to say, it doesn't much matter whether you say let _ = function(); or just function();.  In terms of what happens to the function's return value, they do the same thing at the same point in time.
Additionally, Rust doesn't have a special notion of constructors like C++ does.  Functions that create values can be called "constructor functions" but this is just terminology; at the language level, there is no conceptual difference between a function that creates a Self or any other function.
Rust also doesn't have a concept of pure functions or those with side effects.  If a function is actually pure and the result is unused, the optimizer might be able to determine that the whole thing is a giant no-op, but if the function does have side effects, such as mutating state or doing I/O, the optimizer will be unable to elide the function call in its entirety.
The summary is that the compiler is not going to optimize away that function call, assuming it does have observable side effects2.  This is true regardless of whether or not you use the let _ syntax.

1 The "almost" is that let _ = y; counts as a usage of y, while y on its own does not.  This is commonly used to ignore Results returned from a function when one does not care if the operation failed. let _ = fallible_operation(); will suppress the "unused Result that must be used" warning.
2 As a curiosity, note that Rust does not consider allocation to be a side effect, and therefore allocations can be optimized away in some cases.

Re footnote 2: it's not just allocation that can be optimized away, but also reallocation (ie allocate, move and deallocate); and I refer you also to my comment above re Clone::clone on Copy types.

@eggyal Right, that wasn't supposed to be an exhaustive list of exceptions, just something I found interesting.

Nitpick: The optimizer might as well decide that any function call can be inlined and elide the function call itself, but it can't remove the effectful operations.

@cdhowie It's the second footnote that actually answers my question. (Also note I never used a word "constructor" in my question :))

@cafce25 "Function call" here does not mean "the assembly that calls a non-inlined function" but "the effects of having called the function."
